# Measure on Space of Functions

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Let $\Lambda \subset \mathbb{Z}^{d}$ be a finite set and $\mathbb{R}^{|\Lambda|}$ the set of all sequences of the form $\varphi = (\varphi_{x})_{x\in \Lambda}$. Suppose $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},P)$ is a fixed probability space and, with abuse of notation, suppose $\varphi = (\varphi_{x}(\cdot))_{x\in \Lambda}$ is a *random vector* $\varphi : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}^{|\Lambda|}$. Now, for a measurable function $f: \mathbb{R}^{\Lambda} \to \mathbb{R}$, let us define $F^{\Lambda} :\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ by $F^{\Lambda}(\cdot) := (f\circ \varphi)(\cdot)$. Well, let's imagine that $F^{\Lambda}$ is an element of some function space, so that we think of $F^{\Lambda}$ simply as $f\circ \varphi \equiv f(\varphi)$.

Is there some measure $\tilde{\mu}$ on the space of random variables $\varphi$ satisfying the following equality?
\begin{eqnarray}
\int f(\varphi)d\tilde{\mu} = \int f(\varphi)d\mu_{\Lambda}(\varphi) \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{eqnarray}
Here, in the right hand side of (\ref{1}), $\varphi$ is just an element of $\mathbb{R}^{|\Lambda|}$ and $\mu_{\Lambda}$ is the Borel measure on $\mathbb{R}^{|\Lambda|}$.

Comment: Did you mean to write that $\mu_\Lambda$ is the lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^{|\Lambda|}$? There are lots of Borel measures on that space.

Comment: Yes. I intend to use Borel measure!

Comment: Your answer is confusing. Is $\mu_\Lambda$ the Lebesgue measure or just an arbitrary Borel measure? (note that the Lebesgue measure can be considered as a Borel measure but there are lots of Borel measures that aren't the Lebesgue measure)

Comment: It is the usual Borel measure on $\mathbb{R}^{|\Lambda|} $. If $|\Lambda|=n $ then it is just the usual Borel measure on $\mathbb{R}^{n} $.

Comment: This is an extremely badly written question.

Comment: I must agree to you it is not well written. Actually I'm so lost I'm having trouble even to formulate it preciselly.

Comment: Notation, notation, notation!!...Obviously $\varphi$ on both sides means two different things. So to start clearing the fog, you should use different notations for maps from $\Omega$ to $\mathbb{R}^|{\Lambda}|$ versus single elements of $\mathbb{R}^|{\Lambda}|$. Also, $x$ is distraction here. It is true that an element $\varphi\in\mathbb{R}^{\Lambda}\simeq\mathbb{R}^{|\Lambda|}$ is a function from $\lambda$ to $\mathbb{R}$ but it is better for your question to think of it as just a point in some space.

Comment: You are right. The point here is that I followed Brydges notes and he uses this abuse of notation, so I tried to do the same but I got lost. The other post I made, specifically about Brydges notes (which you posted a generic answer, as you said), was too demanding. I mean, one should really get into Brydges notes to get used to the notation/definitions and answer me, and of course this is too much to ask. So I tried to make a more generic approach to the problem, but my approach got badly written as you pointed out.

Comment: I think I will try to re-elaborate my previous question in a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you cannot guarantee that such a measure $\tilde{\mu}$ exists. For example, you could have made the choice that $\varphi: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}^{|\Lambda|}$ is the random vector such that for each $\omega \in \Omega$ and $x \in \Lambda$, $\varphi(\omega)(x) = 0$. Then take $f$ to be the indicator function $1_{\{\varphi \neq 0\}}$. This means that $F^\Lambda = 0$ so that the left hand side of $(1)$ is $0$ regardless of the choice of $\tilde{\mu}$ but the right-hand side is infinite since $\{\varphi = 0\}$ has Lebesgue measure $0$ in $\mathbb{R}^{|\Lambda|}$.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Comment: From reading the question as it is formulated, the LHS is supposed to be an integral with respect to a measure $\bar{\mu}$ on a rather unwieldy space: the set $\Upsilon$ of all Borel measurable maps from a fixed $\Omega$ into $\mathbb{R}^{|\Lambda|}$. What is the chosen $\sigma$-algebra on $\Upsilon$?